# Show all the nan in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I want to find all the rows which have a specific field as `NaN` using pandas.

I have seem some code on the internet that it says to fillnan with something and find that something. Isn't there any easier way?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `isnull`:

```
In [302]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,np.nan,np.nan, 2], "B": range(4)})

In [303]: df
Out[303]: 
    A  B
0   1  0
1 NaN  1
2 NaN  2
3   2  3

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [304]: df["A"].isnull()
Out[304]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

In [305]: df[df["A"].isnull()]
Out[305]: 
    A  B
1 NaN  1
2 NaN  2

[2 rows x 2 columns]
```